# How is $\mathbb E[ \int_0^T H_s^2 \mathrm d s] < \infty$ important for this claim?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $H=(H_t, t\ge 0)$ be a stochastic process with continuous trajectories. Fix $T>0$. For $n \ge 1$, we define
$$
H_{s,n} := \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} H\left(\frac{(i-1) T}{2^n}\right) 1_{ \left (\frac{(i-1) T}{2^n}, \frac{i T}{2^n} \right]}(s) \quad \forall s \in [0, T].
$$

Then for $(\omega, n) \in \Omega \times \mathbb N$, the map $s \mapsto H_{s, n} (\omega)$ is a step function. Because $H$ has continuous trajectories, we have
$$
H_{s, n} (\omega) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}  H_{s} (\omega) \quad \forall (\omega, s) \in \Omega \times [0, T].
$$

---

It is mentioned at page 35 of this [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc1_final.pdf) that

> **Preliminary fact** If $\mathbb E[ \int_0^T H_s^2 \mathrm d s] < \infty$, then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^T (H_{s,n}-H_s)^2 \mathrm d s\bigg] \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.
> $$

I have tried to verify this statement but got stuck. Could you elaborate on how to prove it?

---

**My attempt**

- Fix $\omega \in \Omega$. We define $f_n:[0, T] \to \mathbb R$ by $f_n (s) := H_{s,n} (\omega)$. We define $f:[0, T] \to \mathbb R$ by $f (s) := H_{s} (\omega)$. Then $\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty  \le \|f\|_\infty < \infty$. Also, $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ pointwise. By dominated convergence theorem, we have
  $$
  \int_0^T (f_n-f)^2 \mathrm d s \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.
  $$
- We define $Y_n:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ by
  $$
  Y_n (\omega) := \int_0^T (H_{s,n} (\omega)-H_s(\omega))^2 \mathrm d s.
  $$
  As proved above, $Y_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ almost surely.

---

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628234/how-is-mathbb-e-int-0t-h-s2-mathrm-d-s-infty-important-for-this-clai) question on MSE but have not received any answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is false in general.

E.g., let $T=1$ and $p_k:=2^{-k}$ for integers $k=1,2,\dots$, so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k=1$. Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be pairwise disjoint events with respective probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots$.
Let
\begin{equation}
    H_t:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{A_k}\,2^k\,\sum_{j=0}^{2^k}\Big(1-8^k\Big|t-\frac j{2^k}\Big|\Big)_+,
\end{equation}
where $u_+:=\max(0,u)$.

Then
\begin{equation}
    E\int_0^1 H_t^2\,dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\; (2^k)^2\,2^k \int_0^1 \Big(1-8^k\Big|t-\frac 1{2^k}\Big|\Big)_+^2\,dt
    =\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\; (2^k)^2\,2^k \frac23\,\frac1{8^k}=\frac23<\infty. 
\end{equation}
On the other hand, for all $t\in(0,1]$ we have $H_{t,n}\ge2^n$ on the event $A_n$, which has probability $p_n=\frac1{2^n}$. So,
\begin{equation}
    E\int_0^1 H_{t,n}^2\,dt\ge(2^n)^2\frac1{2^n}\to\infty
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
    E\int_0^1 (H_{t,n}-H_t)^2\,dt\to\infty\ne0
\end{equation}
as $n\to\infty$. $\quad\Box$

---

The problem here is, of course, that the process $(H_t)$ is not bounded (by a nonrandom constant). A standard construction of the stochastic integral -- see e.g. Proposition 2.6 in Ch. 3 of Karatzas, Ioannis; Shreve, Steven (1991), Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, 2nd ed. -- is done a bit differently: first, the integrand process is truncated to obtain a bounded process, and then the truncated, bounded process is approximated by simple, piecewise-constant processes, and thus the original integrand process is approximated by simple ones (in $L^2(\Omega\times[0,T])$).

Comment: I got that $E\int_0^1 H_t^2 \, dt = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k (2^k)^2 \int_0^1 \big [ \sum_{j=0}^{2^k} \big (1- 8^k \big |t-\frac{\color{red}{j}}{2^k} \big| \big)_+ \big ]^2 dt$. Could you explain how you simplify it to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\; (2^k)^2\,2^k \int_0^1 \Big(1-8^k\Big|t-\frac {\color{red}{1}}{2^k}\Big|\Big)_+^2\,dt
    =\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\; (2^k)^2\,2^k \frac23\,\frac1{8^k}$?

Comment: I have just found the same statement with the same hypothesis (equation *(8.20)*) in [this](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~ecolemathbio2012/Notes/brownien.pdf) note. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @Analyst : The summands in $j$ have mutually disjoint supports. So, they are orthogonal in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @Analyst : Concerning your second comment: In that note, that is OK -- it is emphasized there that the process is *bounded*; so, one can use dominated convergence.

Comment: Ah I meant the claim *"The hypothesis of boundedness can be weakened to the hypothesis
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T H_s^2 d s\right]<\infty
$$*

Comment: @Analyst : As the example above shows, this will not hold in general without boundedness. Perhaps, it is meant in these latter notes that the process is preliminarily truncated, as discussed in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your help!